# How to uncheck a checkbox before disabling it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<coral-checkbox name="chk1" id="p_chk1" class="coral-Form-field" onclick="document.getElementById('p_chk2').disabled=this.checked;">
      Checkbox1
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox name="chk2" id="p_chk2" class="coral-Form-field" disabled>
      Checkbox2
</coral-checkbox>
```

The above enables chk2 only when chk1 is checked (works fine).

Now, if both chk1 and chk2 are checked, and later, on unchecking chk1, though chk2 is disabled, it still remains checked and that messes up the further logic since it evaluates to checked instead of unchecked.

I tried using removeAttr('checked') but that has not helped.
Greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: you are explicitly disabling it `document.getElementById('p_chk2').disabled=this.checked;`

Comment: yes, it is disabled by default and on checking chk1, chk2 is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the `checked` property.

```
<coral-checkbox name="chk1" id="p_chk1" class="coral-Form-field" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('p_chk2').disabled=this.checked; if(this.checked) document.getElementById('p_chk2').checked = false">
      Checkbox1
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox name="chk2" id="p_chk2" class="coral-Form-field" disabled>
      Checkbox2
</coral-checkbox>
```

BTW, I recommend moving the code out to a function, rather than using long inline-JavaScript.

Comment: This worked. Also, using a function instead. Thank you :)